# Valid JSON in text file but python json.loads gives "JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json

I have a valid JSON (checked using Lint) in a text file.

I am loading the json as follows

```
 test_data_file = open('jsonfile', "r")
 json_str = test_data_file.read()
 the_json = json.loads(json_str)
```

I have verified the json data in file on Lint and it shows it as valid. However the json.loads throws

```
 ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I am a newbie to Python so not sure how to do it the right way. Please help
(I assume it has something to do it encoding the string to unicode format from utf-8 as the data in file is retrieved as a string)

Comment: Please copy-paste an example of the contents of `jsonfile`. When I make up my own contents, your code runs perfectly for me.

Comment: If it was an encoding issue you should have received a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Are you sure you are reading the right file? Reading an empty file and thus an empty string will result in a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

Comment: For whatever it is worth, you don't have to call `.read()`. This works: `with open('jsonfile', 'r') as test_data_file: the_json = json.load(test_data_file)`

Comment: @Robᵩ's comment won't necessarily solve your problem, but it does cut down code clutter.  Also, good idea to use the `with` statement to work with files.

Comment: @quirkystack - I'd probably just delete this question if I were you. Just helps keep the site clean :)

Comment: @Wayne Werner was about to delete it.. but just noticed I made a change to the file before I actually read from it.. I am not sure if it made the difference but I edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with open('jsonfile', 'r') and it works now. 
Also I did the following on the file

```
json_newfile = open('json_newfile', 'w')
json_oldfile = open('json_oldfile', 'r')
old_data = json_oldfile.read()
json.dump(old_data, json_newfile)
```

and now I am reading the new file.